# How is String immutable if i can change its value? i understand that i am changing the reference only but then why the 1st scenario is not working?

Tags: java

Consider the two scenarios-

scenario 1:

```
class S{
   String s="hello";
   s="world";
   System.out.println(s);
}
public class StringImmutable{
    public static void main(String args[]){

    }
```

**Result**- it throws uncompiled code error at pkg.StringImmutable.main(StringImmutable.java:12)

but when i do this-

```
class S{
    String s="hello";

    void change(){
        s="world";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
public class StringImmutable{
     public static void main(String args[]){
         S s=new S();
         s.change();
     }
}
```

Result- world..it works just fine.

how is String immutable?enter code here

Comment: You need to differentiate variable from object.

Comment: If a string was immutable then `s1="hello"; s2=s1; s2.change();` would also change s1. What you're doing is changing s to **point to** a different string

Comment: When you do `s="world"`, `s` starts pointing to a new String object ("world"). `"hello"` remains as is in memory to be GCed later on.

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid'Ghouri':- i agree

Comment: New users can google like anyone else. "what does string is immutable mean" yields more than enough results.

Comment: By the way your program is confused by the fact there are 2 variables called `s`, one is a string and the other is a mutable object containing a string

Comment: ok i understand that s is pointing to a new reference but why then the scenario 1 is not working? why it is throwing error ? why not it is pointing to another reference?

Comment: As it's written scenario 1 shouldn't even compile and has an empty main statement so wouldn't do anything anyway

Comment: @RichardTingle--first copy the scenario 1 and run it and then tell me..don't fire bullets in air

Answer (score 4):

You are creating new Strings - no mutation involved. Every time you think you edit a String (i.e. `s1 = s1 + s2`, `s1 += s2`, `s1 = s1.substring(` ...) its the creation of a new String, not a mutation.

Strings are not mutable by design.

Comment: (Not always.  The assignment ('=') does not create a new string.  It is the stuff on the RHS that *may* create the new string.)

Comment: Chapeau ... edited my answer.